# jQuery response is text string. How do I make this a PHP variable?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using a file upload utility that renames files on the backend, then I use a jQuery script to append the file path to a div.

```
'onComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
$('#filesUploaded').append(''+response+'');
}
```

I want to take this response and turn it into a PHP variable that I can use with a form submission.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: by use in a form submission do you mean you want the value to appear in the post data?  If so then write a hidden filed to the form and you should be good.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to be able to send that into my form processing script so I can put it into a database.  I tried creating a hidden field with the same that the div contain had (then removed the div) and it didn't work.

Comment: Is it possible to append a value to a form field with my '+response'?  Perhaps using the attr()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got this working.  Thanks for everyones help.  Here's the code added to a hidden field called filesUploaded:

```
'onComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
$('#filesUploaded').attr('value', ''+response+'');
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I could see you could accomplish this is to create a session-level variable on the page that accepts the file upload. While php can create javascript variables (through scriptlets), the opposite is impossible.

Comment: The file upload happens through AXAJ and the page never refreshes.  

www.uploadify.com is what I am using.  It uses AJAX and then sends the file to a PHP script for processing and formatting.  The new file name is then echo'd back.